# representation type of PI rings

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory

A ring $R$ is said to satisfy a polynomial identity (PI for short) if there exists a polynomial $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{Z} \langle X_1, \ldots, X_n \rangle$ such that $f(r_1, \ldots, r_n)=0$ for each choice $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ in $R$.
If $R$ is a $F$-algebra, for a field $F$, then $R$ is a PI algebra if the polynomial $f$ is in $F \langle X_1, \ldots, X_n \rangle$.

Now suppose that $R$ is a PI-ring or a PI-algebra. What is known about its representation type?

If moreover $R$ is left pure-semisimple (i.e. each left $R$-module is a direct sum of indecomposable left $R$-modules) then Ivo Herzog proved that $R$ has to be of finite representation type.
(For this see I.Herzog, A test for finite representation type, J. Pure and appl. alg. 95, 1994, 151-182).

This is the only result I found. Could it still hold for larger classes?

In any case, I think,  it is not always true. For example take a group algebra $kG$ of a finite group $G$ over a field $k$ of characteristic $p$. Then $kG$ is always PI, but is of finite representation type iff all the $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ are Cyclic.

Thanks!